# How, in a Linux kernel module can I reliably and effeciently determine the NTP clock discipline state

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, ntp

I have a Linux kernel module (a device driver) that needs to know if the kernel time returned via ktime_get_clocktai() is correctly disciplined via NTPd.

This function is required because the time-stamped data that the module produces is meaningless if the time is not synchronised within a few milliseconds to a local LAN based NTP server.

I need to add a flag to the data stream to indicate to the remote receiver that the time stamp is invalid so the data is of low quality.

Currently I am running ntpstat in a user thread, writing the result to a file, then reading that file in the kernel module.

There must be a better way that does not depend on a user space program.

I've looked through the kernel source and can't find any method other than connected to a socket in NTPd to get the kernel clock state.  I would rather not do this as the module is real time.